# Pinescript ATR of different securities

Tags: pine-script

I wanted to use volatility of index for trade filters in my strategy.

In my pinescript code, I can get OHLC values of other stocks/index through security() function. How do I calculate ATR values of the same stock/index. Pinescript ATR function only has argument of length which calculates ATR of chart security which as been selected for backtest. How do I calculate ATR for foreign securities in pinescript?

Answer (score 2):

Pass `ta.atr()` as the `expression` parameter to `request.security()` function. So, the security function would call the atr function on that symbol.

Here, I'm on `BINANCE:BTCUSDT` and request the ATR data of `FX:EURUSD`. You can see that it plots the atr value of `FX:EURUSD` and not `BINANCE:BTCUSDT`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true, precision=5)
atr_eurusd = request.security("FX:EURUSD", "1D", ta.atr(14))
plot(atr_eurusd)
```

[image]

Comment: Legend. I had created a security for daily prices for OLHC and then wrote a formula to calculate ATR. You did this for me in one line. Thanks